# Distinct на основе входимости

Tags: c#, linq

Есть признаки документа и введенные вручную примечания к документу. Признак документа содержит текстовое описание, которое может пересекаться с примечанием. Хочется (и требуется по ТЗ) печатать что-то одно. В идеале - то, что длиннее, но для начала - хотя бы чтобы остался только один.

Пример: в комментарии введено `"поставить печать"`, в признаке - `"Поставить печать!!!"`.

Описан следующий компарер:

```
internal class StringIncludeComparer:IEqualityComparer<string>
{
    public bool Equals(string x, string y)
    {
        if (x.ToUpper().Contains(y.ToUpper())) {return true;}
        if (y.ToUpper().Contains(x.ToUpper())) {return true;}
        return false;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(string obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Собрав в итоге комментарии из документов и комментарии из признаков документов в один `List<{ID, Comment}>` делаю следующее:

```
from trp in tmpPostReport
group trp.Comment by trp.Id
into CommPers
select new { Id= CommPers.Key, Comment = string.Join("; ", 
    CommPers.Distinct(new StringIncludeComparer()).ToArray()) };
```

Но в итоге получаю строку `"поставить печать; Поставить печать!!!"`

Вопрос:

1. Что не так с компарером?
2. Как сделать так, чтобы при сравнении строк "поставить печать" и "Поставить печать!!!" выбиралась всегда большая по длине, т.е. "Поставить печать!!!"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваша проблема в том, что `GetHashCode` не согласован с `Equals`. так делать нельзя. Должно выполняться условие: если `Equals` возвращает `true`, то и хэшкоды должны быть равны.

Например, вы можете вернуть 0 в `GetHashCode`.

---

Для того, чтобы выбрать самую короткую строку, можно попробовать использовать groupby:

```
CommPers.GroupBy(s => s, new StringIncludeComparer())
        .Select(g => g.OrderBy(s => s.Length).First());
```

Но учтите, что для `EqualityComparer`'а ваше отношение равенства должно быть транзитивно, как это отмечено в другом ответе. Поэтому код имеет право и не сработать.

---

Для того, чтобы ваше сравнение **гарантировано работало** несмотря на то, что оно нетранзитивно, применим тяжёлую артиллерию. Откажемся от `IEqualityComparer`'а (так как мы всё равно не можем удовлетворить его инвариант), и сделаем группировку, которая вычисляет транзитивное замыкание вашего равенства: если `Equals(a, b)` и `Equals(b, c)` оба равны true, то мы считаем элементы `a` и `c` равными вне зависимости от `Equals(a, c)` (и так далее). Заметьте, что нам теперь придётся сравнивать (почти) каждый элемент с каждым, так что производительность пострадает.

```
static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    class TransitiveGrouping<K, T> : List<T>, IGrouping<K, T>
    {
        public TransitiveGrouping(K key) { Key = key; }
        public K Key { get; private set; }
        internal List<K> EqualKeys = new List<K>();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<K, T>> TransitiveGroupBy<T, K>(
            this IEnumerable<T> sequence,
            Func<T, K> keySelector,
            Func<K, K, bool> keyComparer)
    {
        var result = new List<TransitiveGrouping<K, T>>();
        foreach (T curr in sequence)
        {
            K currKey = keySelector(curr);
            var containingGroups = result
                    .Where(tg => tg.EqualKeys.Any(kk => keyComparer(kk, currKey)))
                    .ToList();
            if (containingGroups.Count == 0)
            {
                // add a new group
                var newGroup = new TransitiveGrouping<K, T>(currKey);
                newGroup.Add(curr);
                newGroup.EqualKeys.Add(currKey);
                result.Add(newGroup);
            }
            else
            {
                var targetGroup = containingGroups.First();
                targetGroup.Add(curr);
                // merge the groups (transitive closure)
                foreach (var group in containingGroups.Skip(1))
                {
                    targetGroup.AddRange(group);
                    targetGroup.EqualKeys.AddRange(group.EqualKeys);
                    result.Remove(group);
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Теперь ваш запрос должен работать так:

```
CommPers.TransitiveGroupBy(s => s, new StringIncludeComparer().Equals)
        .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(s => s.Length).First());
```

Вот рабочий пример: http://ideone.com/OT2GqM

Я сильно не отлаживал, так что возможны баги. Если что, сообщайте, пофиксим.

Comment: т.е. все экземпляры будут иметь одинаковый хэш? Не получится ли обратной несогласованности - хэш одинаков, а Equals возвращает false?

Comment: @Zufir: А такая согласованность и не требуется. Да и не может быть в принципе. Потому что различных возможных строк гораздо больше, чем значений `int`.

Answer (score 6):

Ответ на вторую часть вопроса - это нельзя сделать в терминах сравнения, потому что сравнение транзитивно (`(a == b, a == c) => a == c`), а ваш механизим сравнения - нет:

```
"поставить печать" == "Поставить печать!!!"
"поставить печать" == "Поставить печать???"
но
"Поставить печать!!!" != "Поставить печать???"
```

Кстати, из-за этого вы будете получать разные результаты при разном порядке входных данных (ес-но, после того, как почините компарер вставив `return 0;` в`GetHashCode`):

```
var values = new List<string> 
{ 
    "поставить печать",
    "Поставить печать!!!",
    "Поставить печать??"
};


var values2 = new List<string> 
{ 
    "Поставить печать!!!",
    "Поставить печать??",
    "поставить печать"
};

// 1
Console.WriteLine(values.Distinct(new StringIncludeComparer()).Count());

// 2!
Console.WriteLine(values2.Distinct(new StringIncludeComparer()).Count());
```

Comment: _Может_ сработать, если сначала отсортировать по длине строки.